# I can't start Mozilla Servo Nightly Build on my Debian 8.5 x64

Tags: linux, firefox, debian, browser, tar

I just downloaded Servo Nightly Build for Linux x64 (by Mozilla, based on Rust) from:
https://servo-builds.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

I followed instructions for Linux (which are pretty simple):
- Click the "Linux Build" button above
- Download the .TAR.GZ file
- Expand the file (`tar zxf servo-latest.tar.gz`)
- `cd servo`
- Execute the `./runservo.sh` script to run Servo

Output for the last command is:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to create window.: OsError("GL
>   context creation failed")', ../src/libcore/result.rs:785 note: Run
>   with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.

'RUST_BACKTRACE=1 ./runservo.sh' gives:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to create window.: OsError("GL
>   context creation failed")', ../src/libcore/result.rs:785 stack
>   backtrace:    1:     0x7f9950b5a80f -
>   std::sys::backtrace::tracing::imp::write::h6528da8103c51ab9    2:
>   0x7f9950b6243b -
>   std::panicking::default_hook::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::hbe741a5cc3c49508
>   3:     0x7f9950b6209f -
>   std::panicking::default_hook::he0146e6a74621cb4    4:
>   0x7f99507cd8a7 -
>   util::panicking::initiate_panic_hook::*$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::*$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::hc61828c8a9f6df01
>   5:     0x7f9950b488ec -
>   std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::h983af77c1a2e581b    6:
>   0x7f9950b62681 - std::panicking::begin_panic::he426e15a3766089a    7: 
>   0x7f9950b4a15a - std::panicking::begin_panic_fmt::hdddb415186c241e7
>   8:     0x7f9950b6261e - rust_begin_unwind    9:     0x7f9950b98c2f -
>   core::panicking::panic_fmt::hf4e16cb7f0d41a25   10:     0x7f994ed366a0
>   - core::result::unwrap_failed::hd132ba2b7d75f379   11:     0x7f994ed354a0 - glutin_app::window::Window::new::h750be0f1f60f008a
>   12:     0x7f994ed34470 - glutin_app::create_window::hae774cdda1762e66 
>   13:     0x7f994ecdd2d5 - servo::main::h6924e5658370f6b5   14:
>   0x7f9950b61a18 - std::panicking::try::call::h852b0d5f2eec25e4   15:
>   0x7f9950b6c87b - __rust_try   16:     0x7f9950b6c81e -
>   __rust_maybe_catch_panic   17:     0x7f9950b614be - std::rt::lang_start::hfe4efe1fc39e4a30   18:     0x7f994c16ab44 -
>   __libc_start_main   19:     0x7f994ecdc299 -    20:                0x0 -

any idea about what to do?
where the bug could be?

thanks
stackexchangist

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/servo/servo/issues/12053